# Is electricity saved by switching off the lights when leaving a room?

Tags: led, energy

Incandescents are very energy inefficient for sure so they have to be turned off whenever you leave the room. But I have tried to find the answer for CFL lights, some say that it's more efficient to leave them on if you will need them again in the next 15 minutes (because of the in-rush current), but others say that it's more efficient to turn them off, because the in-rush current happens in a fraction of a second, so it doesn't waste a lot of energy and is equivalent to just a few seconds of LED's work.

And how to calculate the in-rush current? For example, if I have a 75 W CFL, how do I found out its energy consumption after 1 minute being constantly on and being turned on and off in 5-second intervals?

It would be really helpful if you would give links to already published scientific researches that I have somehow missed.

P.S. I need this for a science project and it would help if you could give some advice on how to prove which way is more energy efficient and calculations are very important.

Comment: AFAIK LED bulbs don't have a significant intrush current, maybe you heared stories about fluorecent lamps? But when in doubt, there is generally one correct answer: measure! Simple power meters can be bought cheaply (at least in my country).

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen Yes, I meant CFL. Sorry for my mistake. But are these power-meters good enough to measure these slight changes? Isn't there really a way to calculate it? And some published scientific researches would be really helpful.

Comment: Remember that the heat from an incandescent lamp is not wasted if the central heating (etc.) is in use.

Comment: @AndrewMorton - that's only treat if the heat is directly electric, which is a horrible way to heat compared to something more direct or (with a suitable outside temperature) using electricity to run a heat pump.  And lightbulbs are poorly positioned even compared to electric heaters.

Comment: Regardless of inrush *current* the energy required for start is less than a fraction of a second of operation, assuming the lamp comes on to full brightness immediately. Some CFL bulbs took some time to come up to full brightness, but ignoring that, there is no time too short (barring pathological cases) that it does not save energy to turn the lights off. Whether that is "worth it" in human terms is a different question, if you stumble about in the darkness and smash a priceless Ming Dynasty vase, the fraction of  a penny you save from turning off a 9W light are probably not worth it to you.

Answer (score 5):

The inrush current issue has nothing to do with saving electricity.

But the inrush current puts a lot of physical stress on the bulb, reducing its lifetime. So the argument that you should leave the light on is about making the bulb last longer (saving money on light bulbs), not about saving the money you spend on electricity.

Obviously, there's eventually a crossover point, where you're spending more on electricity than you would be on replacement light bulbs. But determining exactly where that is will be difficult, because it's hard to quantify the amount of "damage" done to a bulb by each inrush event. It's very much a statistical thing, which would require gathering data on a large number of bulbs over a significant amount of time.

Comment: Thanks for the educational answer. I would really appreciate if you would suggest any other interesting problem that I can make my science project about.

Comment: Inrush is also an issue with tripping circuit breakers.

Comment: If you eliminate the inrush current on cold start in incandescent bulbs, they can last for decades. It happen for me to install some lucky dimmer in a bathroom, and the first bulb (out of six) burned down only after 15 years of use, if I recall correctly.

Comment: What about CFL startup energy? I heard somewhere it can be quite high but would be grateful if you could elaborate